# Returning a specific data type when referring to an object in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, object

Usually when outputting an object in Python, you define the string that is returned in `__repr__`, but what if you want it to return something else instead, like an integer or tuple?

I'll give an example. My class is `Users` and there are member variables `self.username` and `self.email`. If I want to output an object of type `Users`, how do I get it to return `(self.username,self.email)` as a tuple?

Comment: `return repr(integer)` or `return repr(tuple)`?

Comment: Can you give an example of why you would want to do that?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want it to return a tuple such as `("Kevin", "kevin@example.com")` rather than a string that looks like a tuple, such as `'("Kevin", "kevin@example.com")'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The return value from `__repr__` must be a string, and the content of that string should represent a valid Python expression which can be passed to `eval()` to create a new object of that type if possible.

[https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Answer (score 0):

The `__*__` attributes of an object are meant to implement internal functions standardized by the Python language. Like `__add__` (which is used to provide a result of `object + whatever`, `__repr__` is expected to behave in a defined way, which would include to return (a) certain datatype(s).

While statically typed languages will report a compile-time error, for dynamically typed languages like Python, this might result in unexpected (yet not undefined!) runtime behaviour. This need not even result in an error message. Therefore, never change that behaviour to somethin unexpected.

If you want to return something custom, use a custom method like `get_info(self)` or similar. (Remember not to use `__*__` names for that either)